# What is the difference between mozconfig vs moz.configure?

Tags: firefox, open-source

I'm trying to build firefox.

it says to edit my mozconfig file. I see a moz.configure file, but no mozconfig file. Should I edit the moz.configure file or create a mozconfig file?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be changing the `moz.configure` file, as this is a configuration file used internally by the mach build system.

Instead, you should create your own `.mozconfig` file (*don't forget the initial dot!*) and put your customization options in there. Simply `touch .mozconfig` to create the file, then edit it. A brief overview of that file is available on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Configuring_Build_Options).

Comment: Someone else told me that mozconfig without the dot is better. What's the difference?

Comment: The dot at the beginning of a filename is used on Unix/LInux do mark files which shouldn't normally be shown (hidden). But that's not the case on Windows, where they act as normal files. There's no worse and better in this case I guess: just pick the filename you prefer, which might be without a dot if you're on Windows.